# How can I care for my euonymus japonicus president gauthier?

Tags: compost, repotting, wilt

I bought a cheap supermarket mixed planter pot about 3 years ago. I left them outside in a damp, sheltered area with little direct sunlight. The plant I now believe to have identified as *euonymus japonicus president gauthier* flourished while others died.

As recently as 6 weeks ago he was effortlessly surviving snowfall and frost. We joked about how tough he was.
Recently we decided to give him a better home so I repotted him in a larger pot with fresh non-Ericaceous compost.

Unfortunately, he hasn't adjusted to this very well:

- He seems to have wilted and lost a quarter of his leaves.
  [image: Wilted and lost leaves]
- A few of the leaves have curved pieces missing like they've been eaten (a few looked like this before repotting too).
  [image: Leaves with bites?]
- The stem is brown and dry looking in places (this was present though not as noticeable before repotting).
  [image: Stem with brown woody parts]

Please advise how to look after him better or what might be the problem with our *EJPG*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting this plant from the mixed container has probably damaged its roots - the topgrowth will continue to drop leaves because of that damage.  It should recover with proper watering and care, but you need to reduce the topgrowth by two thirds to give it a good chance and to encourage new growth off the roots, so cut it down, otherwise you'll just have lots of bare stems. Keep it watered (assuming that pot has a drainage hole) when it needs it, and don't leave it sitting in water in any tray or outer pot, empty that after 30 minutes.

Euonymus are very tolerant of being cut, and it should regenerate well - I'm assuming you used proper, new potting soil to pot it up with, which should contain some fertilizer already, otherwise, feed it with a balanced NPK fertilizer, something like 7-7-7, after you cut it down.

Comment: OK that makes sense. He was getting quite long and I wondered if he needed pruning back. I will make sure the pot is draining properly - it does have holes. I used Hortons Multi-purpose compost which says it is a specially formulated peat based compost with added nutrients to feed plants for the first 4 -5 weeks after potting. So hopefully that will do the job. Thanks for your advice.